# How to set a temporary fragment to my "home screen" Android studio

Tags: java, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments, layout

I have started coding and I really like it, I have been on/off on diffrent project (to learn diffrent things) But now i got a problem, I "app"reciate all the help i can get.

I am using the navigation drawer and got three fragments installed. I can navigate through the navigation drawer and select a fragment and it loads on my screen. But when i start my app the screen is just white and the navigation drawer is on the left and i can pick a fragment. Is it possible to have a fragment on my "home screen" so when I start the app there is a fragment already placed on the screen BUT! when i chosse another fragment in the navigation drawer i would like to have my fragment who loaded at the beginning to disappear. Otherwise both fragments will show on eachother (Text on text).   Maybe to have the temporary fragment to "finish" itself somehow. Please look at my imgur image to get my idea.[Imgur image press here to view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umrX9.jpg)

Comment: You can just put any `Fragment` in your `onCreate()` method inside your `Activity`. Look into the `FragmentManager`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a generic solution on how to use the `FragmentManager`. It should give a good idea on how to display a `Fragment`. Besides that you could include a static Fragment in your layout. It's up to you how to approach it.
So the `FragmentManager` solution looks like this:

`YourActivity.java`

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragment = AnyFragment.instantiate(this, AnyFragment.class.getName());
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_placeholder, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
    }
```

The target id is defined in your activity `layout.xml`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_placeholder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"></FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

---

Later if you want to replace the current Fragment you can use the `remove` and `add` method of the FragmentManager (the `replace` method is kinda buggy).

```
Fragment currentFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_placeholder))
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(currentFragment).add(R.id.fragment_placeholder, yourNewFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Comment: Ty Murat I will try the code when i get home! Usually sits 2-4 hours when i get home from work hehe :).

Comment: Hi again, It worked!!! I only used this code and it worked perfectly great! < @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragment = AnyFragment.instantiate(this, AnyFragment.class.getName());
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_placeholder, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
    }